# Can Not Install XML Package

Tags: xml, r

I can not install the latest XML package V3.9-4. 
I mannually install it in RGui by typing:

```
install.packages("LOCALDIR/XML_3.6-0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

But get some error message:

```
* installing *source* package 'XML' ...
Please define LIB_XML (and LIB_ZLIB, LIB_ICONV)
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'XML'
* removing 'LOCALDIR/R/win-library/2.12/XML'
* restoring previous 'LOCALDIR/R/win-library/2.12/XML'
```

Anyone any idea?

Thx!

Comment: We need at least your `sessionInfo ()`. And we need to know whether you have devel versions os libxml, zlib and libiconv installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a windows user (at least your path indicates so) and XML is not available for that OS using the standard [binary install](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html).  So I see you've tried source, smart but there are pieces that can't compile without rtools and some magic voodoo.  So you got two choices:

1. Learn the magic voodoo to make it install correctly
2. Go to the CRAN
   site and the [read me file](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/ReadMe), which tells you Professor Ripley has
   put them together for you [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/).  This is good to know because
   RCurl is there too.  For a direct download of the package click
   [HERE](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/XML_3.9-4.1.zip).

I can't help you with the voodoo as I opted for the second choice :)

Comment: Thx a lot! Busy with other stuff, I will have a look at this soon!

Comment: @Tyler Rinker The third link you supplied for the direct download of the package appears to be broken.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this for myself today, noting it here for prosperity.

On Unbuntu systems, you can fix this by loading `libxml2-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

After I did that, `install.packages("XML")` ran without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a punt but I had a similar problem some time ago and it was something to do with having another version of iconv.dll (?) available. I think my rogue version came via cygwin. Making that version unavailable fixed the problem.

P.S. I am on Windows and have XML installed. Just from the straight binary.

Comment: Thx a lot! Busy with other stuff, I will have a look at this soon!

Comment: I didn't try this as there is already an existing package provided by professor Ripley. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use the windows binary directly from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html

You will go into your R library director and unzip it there.