# Error installing RCurl and XML packages on Windows

Tags: xml, r, installation, rcurl

I am trying to install the RCurl and XML packages and getting an error on Windows. I have tried R 2.15.0 and 2.15.1, cran.r-project.org and www.omegahat.org/R, and binary and source. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
install.packages('RCurl',repos='http://www.omegahat.org/R', type='source')
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/R/R-2.15.0/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 862526 bytes (842 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 842 Kb

* installing *source* package 'RCurl' ...
Please set LIB_CURL
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-2.15.0/library/RCurl/libs
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-2.15.0/library/RCurl/libs
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-215~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-215~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
gcc  -I"C:/R/R-215~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -Wall -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FILETIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIVATE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_APPEND=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USE_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CRLFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 
-DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c base64.c -o base64.o
In file included from base64.c:1:0:
Rcurl.h:4:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [base64.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RCurl'
* removing 'C:/R/R-2.15.0/library/RCurl'
Warning in q("no", status = 1, runLast = FALSE) :
  cannot get info on 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\Rtmp2fO9aA/R.INSTALL4245e223b81/RCurl', reason 'Access is denied'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'C:/R/R-215~1.0/bin/i386/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/R/R-2.15.0/library"   C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\RtmpclrXFX/downloaded_packages/RCurl_1.95-1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\RtmpclrXFX\downloaded_packages

Comment: Maybe [Can Not Install XML Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429390/can-not-install-xml-package) is useful for you

Comment: Suggestion: install from CRAN instead of Omegahat.  There are only a few [Windows binaries on Omegahat for R-2.15.x](http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/).  And you probably can't install from source because you haven't correctly setup the build environment, and/or you're not following directions about which tools to use (i.e. not Cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

You have cygwin issues, so probably you didn't have RTools.